# Shopify theme license

Tags: themes, shopify, license-key

I build a new Shopify theme and want to sell it in the market but before that, I want to make sure that no one can use it without purchasing the theme license. How I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a question for Shopify technical support.

Comment: This question is off-topic for SO, asking on Shopify-related forms or contacting Shopify support would be a better option.

Answer (score 2):

Its possible but for that you need to setup your our server and create a database.

In the database create a table and add the following feilds.

```
domain, customer_name, customre_emaIl, store_URL, theme_status, lic_key
```

Then in the theme code you need to add some JS code and trigger AJAX call to your server with the store info and unique License key to validate the theme.

Now the trick is to hide you JS code in the theme. There are several methods i.e.

- Use "eval()" function
- Unicode

This is the basic idea behind the Licensed theme. For your reference the following theme is using this technique (I already worked on this theme that's why I know) :
[Shoptimized](https://shoptimized.net/theme/)

Thanks and best of luck